# Random Variable Name, It's Possible?

Tags: c++, c, variables, random

Imagine if for any reason, you want to **create several variables, and without using an array**, and they **must have different names**. Logically, you will not create empty variables and set 500 only as needed.

**In short, it is possible to generate a variable with the same name without the random use of an array or vector?**

*If possible, I would like the instantiation logic or C or C++.*

I've tried in this method (In C), but doesn't work:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for random

#define RANDOM random(100)

int main ( void )
{
    int n/**/RANDOM = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

Possibly older compilers work, because they remove the comment. Current compilers consider the comment as a space.

Comment: How would you access a variable with random name? :)

Comment: I need to ask, why in heaven would you need to do such a thing? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I suppose it's out of pure curiosity, but in case it's not, how would you then use the variable if its name is random?

Comment: Well, my close vote was for "too localized" for what it's worth. Seems like a real enough question, just not of interest to anybody.

Comment: This might be useful if you are compiling another language into C.

Comment: It is rather curious. And I went to save her name in an array. Not much logic to use it, but it's just curiosity.

Comment: @David is there a policy that only questions that are interested to everybody are posted here?   Just because something is not interesting for you, it doesn't mean it is not interesting for everybody.  Please think twice before voting to close next time.

Comment: @MK I judged that the question matched the "too localized" reason for closing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, then read what "too localized" means?

Comment: @mk I know what it means. If I'm wrong others can vote to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least on recent GCC, you can use tricks like

```
 #define NEWVAR_NUM(Var,Num) { static int Var_##Num; foo(&Var_##Num); }
 #define NEWVAR(Var) NEWVAR_NUM(Var,__COUNTER__)
```

On other (or with standard conforming) compilers, you can use `__LINE__` instead of `__COUNTER__`. See [Common Predefined Macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) of GCC and cpp's [concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation)

Also, you could consider generating such contrived C code, with e.g. [m4](http://www.gnu.org/s/m4/) or your own generator (which can be a ten line script or a 100K line generator).

Comment: Doesn't work in gcc 4.8.5, __COUNTER__ would never expand.

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like this:

```
#define CONCAT_INTERNAL(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_INTERNAL(a, b)

int CONCAT(var, __LINE__);
int CONCAT(var, __LINE__);
int CONCAT(var, __LINE__);
```

The indirection through `CONCAT_INTERNAL` is necessary, since otherwise the tokens `var` and `__LINE__` are concatenated before the `__LINE__` is evaluated.

This preprocessor trick is widely used, e.g. in [NetBSD](https://nxr.netbsd.org/xref/src/sys/sys/cdefs.h#84).

Comment: I'm using this to attempt to avoid multiple evaluation: `#define SQUARE(x) int CONCAT(__tmp_, __LINE__) = (x), tmp *  tmp`. (Nevermind, this fails horribly).

Comment: What about `static inline int sqr(int x) { return x * x; }`?

Comment: in gcc 4.8.5 __LINE__ doesn, expand. The error is: /home/valentinheinitz/Workspaces/hitrax3/trunk/sinogrambuffer/src/sinogrambuffer/sinogrambufferLib/sinogramBuffer.cc:29: Error: redefinition of 'int var__LINE__'
 int CONCAT(var, __LINE__);
     ^

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Oops, I could reproduce that and have fixed the code. Weird that it takes more than five years to find such an obvious bug.

Answer (score 5):

The lifecycle of your program is:

1. source code is preprocessed
2. source code is compiled
3. resulting binary is executed

Call to random can only happen during the execution stage.
You are trying to do it at the preprocessing stage.  Will not work, period.

Regarding your question -- it just makes no sense, explain what is it that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The question was perhaps wrongly phrased, but does make sense. Random was meaning "unique" or "difficult to forge"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't do that using a function from `<stdlib.h>` because those are run-time; what you need is a compile-time construct.

The only way to do something like this would be to use the preprocessor, but C/C++'s preprocessor is very basic. It has no variables which you might increment and it certainly has no function that generates random numbers.